# Swagger annotation for query parameters for file upload

Tags: symfony, swagger-ui

I am trying to make an api documentation for my symfony based api and I would like to add info about the upload endpoint for my api. I am using nelmioapidocbundle. Can anyone please provide a link to the documentation where I can find it? or better if there is an example. Thank you.

```
/**
 * @Route("/products/{id}/images", methods={"POST"})
 * 
 * @SWG\Parameter(
 *      name="file",
 *      in="body",
 *      type="file",
 *      ---- Im not sure what to put here to make this work
 * )
 * 
 * @SWG\Response(
 *          response=201,
 *          description="File is uploaded."
 *      )
 * )
 */
public function uploadImages(Request $request, FileUploadService $fileUploadService) {}
```

Answer (score 2):

For anyone who might encounter this. this formData in value fixed the problem:

```
 * @SWG\Parameter( 
 *      name="file", 
 *      in="formData", <----
 *      required=true, 
 *      type="file", 
 *      description="product image"
```